# Intel C++ Compiler for Windows CE 

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, embedded, windows-ce

Two years ago I used eMbedded Visual Studio for Windows CE based application development. I had about 40% app performance acceleration with Intel C++ Compiler(v1.2 or v2.0) in comparison with default MS compiler (floating point issues, ARM). It was looked really helpful for me.

I do remember that downloaded it from official Intel site. At that time I saw a lot of information there about this compiler and many press releases.

It's appear I need to solve performance problem again with my new Windows CE (5.0) platform. I've tried to find actual compiler for Windows CE at Intel web-site (hoped to VS2008 integration). But I cannot find anything... even version I used before! I was surprised, it looks like this product no longer exist... (just 2005 year dated comments at forum).

**Can somebody explain what happens with this product?**

P.S.: Here is a [link (Intel web-site)](http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/compilers/219762.htm) where Intel C++ Compiler for Windows CE mentioned! But "Page Not Found" 
http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/compilers/219762.htm

Comment: This is a good question.  Going through their website suggests that they've canceled it in favor of their atom development compilers, which seems pretty silly to me.  Could the CE compiler have been rolled into the general windows compiler?  Since version 11 supports vs2008, it may be that you can download the windows compiler and set your target to winCE.  That's just a guess, though.

Comment: For Windows CE based on x86 architecture probably yes.... we just need to use  general windows compiler. But for xScale architecture it is not suitable.

Sorry... in my question I should accent xScale architecture promptly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not too surprising. Since Intel intends to get to the embedded market with Atom they sold the XSCALE department to Marvell along with all other related products. I just checkd Marvell's extranet and they have a C++ compiler for Windows CE V2.2, dedicated for the XSCALE technology. You need to register to the extranet though, and Marvell decides wether to give you access permissions.

---

PS

I referred to XSCALE and not x86 because the Windows CE compiler specified in the web page you gave the link to refres to that technology. I don't know if Intel ever had a C++ compiler for x86 under Windows CE.

Comment: Is the XScale the successor to DEC's StrongARM family? Does that make Marvell's PXA chips a modern take on a DEC design?

Comment: From Wiki, the answer is yes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StrongARM). Seems it was StrongArm->Intel Xscale-> Marvell Xscale

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes... I mean xScale (ARM) processors.