# How to compile application for wince 5.0 x86 using VS

Tags: visual-studio, x86, windows-ce, intel

i was looking for a way of compiling application for wince 5.0 x86 using VS. I found a thread [Intel C++ Compiler for Windows CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313001/intel-c-compiler-for-windows-ce)  where you mentioned  ... "For Windows CE based on x86 architecture probably yes.... we just need to use general windows compiler."

I was wondering if you could provide more details on how to set up visual studio project.

Answer (score 0):

To compile an application that targets the x86 cpu you need to create a new Smart Device application using Visual Studio and choose a platform that is x86.

During the wizard of a new application you get to a screen in which you choose your target platform (a list of installed SDKs is displayed). If you choose an SDK that is for x86, then the program will be compiled using the x86 option.

Bottom line, Visual Studio includes the compiler for x86 devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do Pocket PC development without the usage of the full Visual Studio, this article was written on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/WiMoSansVS.aspx) which utilized the Express editions to enable development of Pocket PC applications.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: This is for managed code.  I'm not certain it's going to be even this straightforward for native, and I think the custom x86 SDK he would require won't install without detecting Studio first.

Comment: @ctacke: Oh...I did not realize he meant unmanaged...I was under the impression he was talking about using VS to build a managed solution for WinCE 5.0....good catch there...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Microsoft ActiveSync 4.0 or later and the respective mobile SDK.

For ActiveSync 4.5: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/downloads/microsoft/activesync-download.mspx

Win CE 5.0 SDK:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fa1a3d66-3f61-4ddc-9510-ae450e2318c3&displaylang=en

Happy Coding!

Comment: You don't need ActiveSync at all, and I'd highly discourage using the Standard SDK.  You should always use an SDK for the actual target device else you run the risk of ending up with something that builds but won't run.